# Connecting to a MongoCryptD instance in docker environment with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose, docker-network

I've searched over the web but couldn't find my answer anywhere.
I'm trying to run an API web service, using NestJS framework.

I'm running docker-compose that spins up the API server, a MongoDB instance, and a mongocryptd instance to allow Client-Side Field Level Encryption on my app.

I'm able to connect to the MongoDB instance, but not to the mongocryptd instance.

## Docker-Compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      labels:
        env: dev
      args:
        APP: appname
        APP_PORT: 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: ["sh", "-c", "npm run start:app:dev"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  mongodb:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/MongoEP-Dockerfile
      labels:
        env: dev
      args:
        MONGO_PACKAGE: mongodb-enterprise
        MONGO_REPO: repo.mongodb.com
    image: mongo-enterprise:4.2.5
    command: ["--auth"]
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: usr
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes: ["/private/var/services/mongodb:/data/db"]

  mongocryptd:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/MongoEP-Dockerfile
      labels:
        env: dev
      args:
        MONGO_PACKAGE: mongodb-enterprise
        MONGO_REPO: repo.mongodb.com
    image: mongo-enterprise:4.2.5
    entrypoint: mongocryptd
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27020:27020"
    volumes: ["/private/var/services/mongodb:/data/db"]
```

The used dockerfile is mongo's official dockerfile, but supplied with args to build an enterprise version of the image which includes the enterprise features.

When trying to connect to the database from the app, I'm running:

```
MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb://usr:pwd@mongodb:27017`, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      retryAttempts: 2,
      autoEncryption: {
        keyVaultNamespace,
        kmsProviders,
        extraOptions: {
          mongocryptdURI: `mongodb://mongocryptd:27020`,
          mongocryptdBypassSpawn: true
        }
      } as any
    })
```

** *This is the NestJS version of supplying the configs. it's similar to mongoose - the first argument is the URI and the second is the settings object*

---

Without the autoEncryption options, I'm able to connect without any problems. That means that my database address is correct.
With the autoEncyption options, I'm getting `MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.4:27020` (mongocryptd address). That means that the IP is correct (DNS resolved), but the connection is refused. As I showed before, the port (27020) is being published by the docker-compose file, and I even tried to add an EXPOSE step in the build itself.

**BUT** when I map the network of the containers to host (`network_mode: "host"`), the application is able to connect without any problems (changing the connections DNS to localhost:27017 and 27020 of course). So that must mean it's a docker-related problem.

### Additional things I've tried && a recap of what I tried:

- Attach a volume to replace `/etc/mongod.conf.orig` with the following network configurations:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  bindIpAll: true
```

- Instead of attaching a volume, replacing it ^ at the build step before launching the mongo service.
- I also tried changing the `bindIp` to the specific application IP that was given by the docker network.
- All types of connection strings with & without user credentials, auth source, and default database.
- Port 27020 is published in docker-compose & exposed on docker file.

I ran out of ideas. Any help is appreciated! :)

#### EDIT:

After more debugging, I can see that `mongod` is running with `--bind_ip_all` by default so changing the conf file shouldn't have an effect.
Tried also running `mongocryptd` with mongods `docker-entrypoint.sh` entrypoint instead of overriding it.

Comment: can you share your updated dockerfile? I am facing this issue as well. thanks!

Comment: @BenLuk just add these lines to install the mongocrypt process on the same container -

```
RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-enterprise/4.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y mongodb-enterprise-cryptd  \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: @AsafKfir Have you succeed exposing  port 27020(mongocryptd) from container to the host? --bind_ip_all only works for mongod

Comment: @hksfho Nope. , I just gave up and installed the mongodb-enterprise-cryptd package inside the app container. It works flawlessly but this is not the optimal solution.

Comment: @AsafKfir you can check my answer

Comment: @hksfho I'm not longer working for the company that did it, so I can not verify it but I'm very glad there is a possible and better solution! Great job

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify `mongocryptd` is running (`ps awwxu`, etc.)
2. Verify you can connect to it from `bash` on the same container where it is running using `mongo`.
3. Verify you can connect to it from host system using `mongo`.
4. Check `mongocryptd` logs (it's basically a `mongod` with some extra functionality).

Comment: 1. I can verify it is running under the root user using `ps awwxu`.
2.  I'm getting a failed, connection refused error - that's because i'm not running the mongod process on that container, just the mongocryptd. I've tried running both mongod & mongocryptd from the same container (run mongo regular image, open a shell, run mongocryptd), but I'm getting the same connection refused error.
3. Again, no mongod is running
4. The logs are empty. I can see just start up logs `[listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
&  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27020`

Comment: I've re-run both mongocryptd and mongo from the same container and scanned the ports with Nmap. Both 27017 & 27020 are stated as open. I'm not getting a connection refused when using mongo CLI, and I'm able to connect from the app if I omit the option to use mongocryptd in the connection settings (autoEncryption key from the example above). When I re-add the encryption key, it tries to connect to mongocryptd and i'm getting the same ECONNREFUSED error. Again, when using the host network mode, everything works.

Comment: Work through the steps, mongo shell can connect directly to a mongocryptd process and at least run ismaster on it.

Comment: There is something that I'm probably not fully understanding. For clarification - does  `mongocryptd` have to replace `mongod` completely? Or should I run both? Because they listen on different ports. That also means, that I'm probably erroneous by running them in separate containers? (As I said, when running both in the same container It's not working as well, but at least I'll know how to debug further).

Comment: mongod and mongocryptd perform different functions. You can run them in the same container or different containers.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I'm able to connect with Mongo() command when both process under the same container, `Mongo("localhost:27020", { keyVaultNamespace: "encryption.__dataKey", kmsProviders: { local: { key: BinData(0, "masterkey") } } })` . The connection is shown in the logs of mongocryptd. I'm not able to perform any encryption operations against the database such as `db.getMongo().getKeyVault();`
Also, I can't connect to `mongocryptd` outside that container either through Mongo() / nodejs driver.

Comment: Your question does not say how mongod and mongocryptd are configured (command line arguments and configuration files). For the purposes of network connectivity, mongocryptd is just like mongod with the only difference being the default port number. Ensure your bind ip is set correctly in server config for both daemons, ensure you are connecting to the correct ip. If you are using "localhost" ensure the process is listening on both ipv4 and ipv6.

Comment: I've done that. They are configured with default configurations (and I've tried passing the conf file settings explained above as well). Currently, I couldn't solve this problem. My best guess is the reason mongocryptd doesn't have an option to bind to an other IP other than localhost (doesn't accept it in the .conf file and there is no option to pass it as a command argument). After 3 days, I just gave up and installed the mongodb-enterprise-cryptd package inside the app container. It works flawlessly but this is not the optimal solution.

Comment: You are right, mongocryptd does not appear to recognize --bind_ip.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with mongocryptd, but I was installing `php` node instead of `npm`. Tried different solutions but didn't managed to succeed. Even tried similar  `Asaf Kfir` `docker-composer.yaml` with pre-installed `mongodb-enterprise-cryptd` lib, but had same issue. Keep in mind, in php node via `Dockerfile` I already been able to install `libmongocrypt-dev` and
`mongodb-enterprise-cryptd`. (I will leave php Dockerfile below)

Those three containers I managed to link under the same ip address, tested with `ncat` and I was able to reach. But when I tried to run tests from php node, it start throwing:

`MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException: Bulk write failed due to previous MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: key vault error: Invalid reply to find command.`

and had this issue for two weeks. Basically didn't know how to resolve it.

P.S. remember these words: `The automatic feature of field level encryption is only available in MongoDB Enterprise 4.2 or later`

At that time my `docker-compose.yaml` file looked like that:

```
version: '3'
services:

    #PHP Service
    php:
        image: local-base-php
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
            - "27020:27020"
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: app
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/projects
            - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

    #MongoDB Service
    mongodb:
        image: local-mongo-db
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
            MONGO_INITDB_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        network_mode: service:php
        volumes: ["/tmp/mongodb:/data/db"]

    #MongoDB Service
    mongocryptd:
        image: local-mongocryptd
        container_name: mongocryptd
        entrypoint: mongocryptd
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        network_mode: service:php
        volumes: ["/tmp/mongodb:/data/db"]

volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: local
```

Mongo images where build from here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-with-docker/

**I managed to solve this issue like this:**
Instead of building `mongo-enterprise` image I accidentally build up with official mongo image `mongo:4.2` and everything worked well. I don't know why mongo says that `enterprise` is needed for encryption. Because for me `mongo-enterprise` encryption didn't worked. The original `mongo:4.2` image worked perfectly.

working `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:

    #PHP Service
    php:
        image: local-base-php
        container_name: app
        restart: always
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: app
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/projects
            - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

    #MongoDB Service
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:4.2
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: always
        tty: true
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
            MONGO_INITDB_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        network_mode: service:php
```

`php node Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip unzip libzip-dev git mercurial zlib1g-dev libicu-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libssl-dev libssh2-1-dev libgmp-dev libpng-dev uuid-dev

RUN cd /tmp && git clone https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-ssh2 && cd /tmp/pecl-networking-ssh2 \
    && phpize && ./configure && make && make install \
    && echo "extension=ssh2.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-ssh2.ini \
    && rm -rf /tmp/ssh2

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gmp

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip json pdo pdo_mysql curl opcache bcmath sockets gmp gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl

RUN pecl install uuid pcov redis mongodb

RUN docker-php-ext-enable uuid pcov redis mongodb

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash -s -- --install-dir /usr/local/bin

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -L -sS "https://github.com/splitsh/lite/releases/download/v1.0.1/lite_linux_amd64.tar.gz" | tar xvz -C /usr/local/bin

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y curl gpg wget

RUN sh -c 'curl -s https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/libmongocrypt.asc | gpg --dearmor >/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/libmongocrypt.gpg'

RUN echo "deb https://libmongocrypt.s3.amazonaws.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/libmongocrypt/1.0 universe" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libmongocrypt.list

RUN wget -qO - mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add -

RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-enterprise/4.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libmongocrypt-dev && apt-get install  --no-install-recommends -y mongodb-enterprise-cryptd
```

I hope I helped. Cheers!

UPDATE:
My tests are running without `libmongocrypt-dev` lib, so I guess you only need `mongodb-enterprise-cryptd`.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use `socat` forwarding traffic

`Dockerfile`:

```
# Build stage
FROM ubuntu:focal

ENV ENTRY_FILE=docker-entrypoint.sh
ENV MONGODB_PATH=/usr/src/mongodb
ENV ENTRY_POINT=$MONGODB_PATH/$ENTRY_FILE

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install sudo
RUN sudo apt-get install -y curl telnet vim socat libcurl4 libgssapi-krb5-2 libldap-2.4-2 libwrap0 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit snmp openssl liblzma5

RUN curl -k -o mongodb.tgz "https://downloads.mongodb.com/linux/mongodb-linux-$(arch)-enterprise-ubuntu2004-5.0.10.tgz"
RUN tar -xf mongodb.tgz --strip-components=1

RUN sudo ln -s $MONGODB_PATH/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
RUN sudo mkdir -p /data/db
RUN sudo mkdir -p /data/log
RUN sudo chown `whoami` /data/db
RUN sudo chown `whoami` /data/log

COPY ./$ENTRY_FILE $ENTRY_POINT
RUN chmod +x $ENTRY_POINT
ENTRYPOINT $ENTRY_POINT
```

`docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:27017,fork,bind=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}') TCP:127.0.0.1:17017 &
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:27018,fork,bind=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}') TCP:127.0.0.1:17018 &
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:27019,fork,bind=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}') TCP:127.0.0.1:17019 &
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:27020,fork,bind=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}') TCP:127.0.0.1:17020 &

./bin/mongod --port 17017 --dbpath /data/db --logpath /data/log/mongod.log &
./bin/mongocryptd --port 17020 --logpath /data/log/mongocryptd.log
```

`$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')` is the remote ip(my docker host ip, 172.2.x.x), you can change to your another container ip.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
    ABC:
        external: false
        name: ABC

services:
    mongo-database:
        container_name: MongoDB
        privileged: true
        build:
            context: .docker/db
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .mongo/db:/data/db
            - .mongo/log:/data/log
        ports:
            - 27017-27020:27017-27020
        networks:
            - ABC
```